# Why is my var undefined when using classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to JavaScript, why is `this.main` undefined on Index.js line 7?

Main.js

```
class Main {

    constructor(hostname, port) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.port = port;
    }

    init() {
        const express = require("express");
        const app = express();

        console.log("Starting server on port: " + this.port);
        app.listen(this.port);

        const index = require("./index/Index");
        const indexI = new index(this);

        app.get("/", indexI.handle);
    }
}

module.exports = Main;
```

Index.js

```
class Index {
    constructor(main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    handle(req, res) {
        return res.send("MAIN: " + this.main);
    }
}

module.exports = Index;
```

I need my Index.js to access my Main.js class instance.

**EDIT:**

I figured out that if I change:
`app.get("/", indexI.handle);`
to

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {indexI.handle(req, res)});
```

It works, why is that?

Comment: If you put your code in a snippet, people could try running it and see the error. You can edit your question and use the `<>` button to add a snippet.

Comment: For best practices, avoid writing `require` in the methods, you may get unexpected runtime error or other problems since you don't have the dependencies ready on the start of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `indexI.handle` to `app.get`, you are simply passing the function, the `this` in the scope of the function is not the instance of `Index`.

Try this

```
app.get("/", indexI.handle.bind(indexI));
```

Comment: It worked. I also edited my question with another fix that I found. Is your answer better than my edit?

Comment: Both are solving the issue in the same manner, but I prefer `.bind()` instead of wrapping the function, because it could be more dynamic.

Comment: you answer is missing a `)` :p

Comment: @Jaromanda X, P.S. untested